# Помогите распарсить сообщение iso8583 с помощью java

Tags: java

Сообщение:

```
3038313082200000020000000400000000000000111312532012345630300301
```

Пытаюсь вот так :

```
ISOMessage isoMessageUnpack = ISOMessageBuilder.Unpacker()
        .setMessage(hexString)
        .build();
System.out.println("isoMessageUnpack " + isoMessageUnpack.getField(FIELDS.F11_STAN));
```

Не работает. Выдает null. Пользуюсь пока либой - https://github.com/imohsenb/ISO8583-Message-Client-java

еще вот такой код попробовал, тоже не работает распарсивание:

```
import org.jpos.iso.packager.ISO87BPackager;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOUtil;

public class ParseISOMsg {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ISOException {
        String hexmsg = args[0];
        // convert hex string to byte array
        byte[] bmsg =ISOUtil.hex2byte(hexmsg);
        ISOMsg m = new ISOMsg();
        // set packager, change ISO87BPackager for the matching one.
        m.setPackager(new ISO87BPackager());
        //unpack the message using the packager
        m.unpack(bmsg);
        //dump the message to standar output
        m.dump(System.out, "");
    }
}
```

выдает

```
exception :

Exception in thread "main" org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC: Problem unpacking field 23 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32) unpacking field=23, consumed=31
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:340)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:468)
    at ParseISOMsg.main(ParseISOMsg.java:16)
```

Comment: А, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Мне надо получить данные из этого, примерно такие: Message type 0810
P0007 Transmission date and time LEN=10 OFFS=20 '0000000000'
P0011 Systems Trace Audit Number LEN=6 OFFS=30 '000000'
P0039 Response code LEN=2 OFFS=36 '00'
P0006 Network Management Code LEN=3 OFFS=38 '000' из hex (is08583) данного сообщения - 3038313082200000020000000400000000000000111312532012345630300301

Comment: Я описал по моему проблему. Можете, что то подсказать пожалуйста?